# Trouble authenticating with Google Content API for Shopping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use [OAuth2 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#libraries) in conjunction with [Google's Content API for Shopping](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/) using the [google-api-client gem](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/) and Ruby on Rails 3.2.5. Also, I have already set up my merchant account as prescribed in the Content API documentation.

This was the best way I found to be able to:

- create/update products in the background
- have created products fall under my company's Google Products 'umbrella'
- not require every user to authenticate/authorize when their token expires

Using lines 1 - 23 from [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/source/browse/service_account/analytics.rb?repo=samples) as a starting point, I've begun to write the following module for use in background jobs:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'google/api_client'

module GoogleProducts
  GOOGLE_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "google.yml"))[Rails.env]

  CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
  MERCHANT_ID = "XXXXXXX"
  SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/structuredcontent"

  KEY_FILE_PATH = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "my-privatekey.p12")
  KEY_FILE_PASS = "XXXXXXXXXX"

  def self.add_item(item_id)
    self.fetch_token
    xml = self.gen_item_xml(item_id)
    headers = {"Content-type" => "application/atom+xml", "Content-Length" => xml.length.to_s}
    url = "https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/#{MERCHANT_ID}/items/products/generic?access_token=#{$gp_token}"

    response = HTTParty.post(url, :body => xml, :headers => headers).parsed_response
  end

  def self.gen_item_xml(item_id)
    #building product xml
  end

  private
  def self.fetch_token
    api_client = Google::APIClient.new(:authorization => :oauth2)
    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(KEY_FILE_PATH, KEY_FILE_PASS)
    asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(CLIENT_ID, SCOPE, key)

    begin
      api_client.authorization = asserter.authorize

      #todo - store in something other than a global
      $gp_token = api_client.authorization.access_token
    rescue Signet::AuthorizationError => e
      puts e.message
    ensure
      return $gp_token
    end
  end
end
```

Everything seemingly works fine - the authentication, the handling of the auth token - until I attempt to actually add an item, which I get the following when I do:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>ServiceForbiddenException</code>
    <internalReason>Could not find authenticated customer</internalReason>
  </error>
</errors>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much anguish and mental toil, I've finally solved my issue!

Since I am using [**OAuth 2 Server to Server authentication**](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#libraries) the suggestion hjblok gave didn't apply (thanks for giving it a shot, though!).

I simply added the email address that was associated with my Service Account key from the Google API Console (e.g. `XXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) to my Google Merchant account (`Settings > Users` on the merchant admin page), and it worked.

If there's any clarification needed, please feel free to comment!

Comment: I'm trying to post a product like you did, and also retrieve and for some reason I keep getting a "ServiceForbiddenException": `<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceForbiddenException</code><internalReason>Could not find authenticated customer</internalReason></error></errors>`
Any ideas? Maybe it has something to do with subaccounts?

Comment: Actually scratch that, I re-read your comment and now the authentication works. I get a different error `<error><domain>Shopping</domain><code>validation/invalid_value</code><location type='other'>link</location><internalReason>We couldn't understand the web address (URL) you submitted. Please check the format of your URL.</internalReason>`, but hopefully I'll figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Content API documentation says you need to set it up in the Settings page of the Google Merchant Center:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/getting-started/usingapi-products

Comment: I've already set up my merchant account (verified and claimed my domain, set up global tax and shipping information). Thanks for the tip, though! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** rewrote the answer after diving into the Google's API documentation

Did you already try to use Google's [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? I was able to successfully access `https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/#{MERCHANT_ID}/items/products/generic`.

1. In "Step 1" I've chosen the "Content API for Shopping" and then authorized the API with my account.
2. Then in "Step 2" I've "exchanged authorization code for tokens", which results in a "refresh token" and an "access token".
3. Then in "Step 3" I've invoked a `GET` request to `https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/1234567/items/products/generic`. Because `1234567` is not a valid `MERCHANT_ID` it returns an Error. But the Error Messages contains a `MERCHANT_ID` which actually belongs to your account.
4. I repeated "Step 3" but now with the correct `MERCHANT_ID`. Which returns a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with the requested items in the body.

Furthermore I'm not sure, but doesn't Google API expect an Authorization header to be present with the `access_token` (`$gp_token`)? Within the [OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) this Authorization header is used to sent the `access_token`.

I also found the Structured Content API demo page (https://google-content-api-tools.appspot.com/demo/demo.html), which is more specific to the Content API for Shopping.

Comment: By the way, a good [example](https://github.com/mbleigh/twitter-auth/blob/master/lib/twitter_auth.rb) of a module for handling API calls is in the twitter-auth gem from mbleigh.